# Solving a system of equations with inequalities ? all solutions needed?

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

I have a set of variables $\{x_{ij}\} \in \{1,2,3,4\}$ such that $1\leq i\leq 5$ and $1\leq j\leq 4$. And the following set of equations :
$$\forall i : \sum_{j}x_{ij} =4$$
$$\forall i \forall i' \exists j : x_{ij} + x_{i'j} \geq 1 $$

Is there any computational solver that will give me all solutions to this problem ?

Comment: All the ILP solutions I have seen seen to be for optimisation of a cindition subject to such constraint, I rather want all solution

Comment: Hi, thanks alot I researched a bit on what you suggested and implemented the problem in python with a Z3 wrapper and the code for blocking solutions given here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867611/z3py-checking-all-solutions-for-equation